# Fill remaining horizontal space in multirow flex layout ("flex-grow: 1" does not work)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### Desired result

Blue cell must fill remaining horizontal space.
Below view has been reached by hardcode.

[image]

### Listing and fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ypLau3d/)

```html
<div class="PseudoTable" role="table">
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">A</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 1</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 2</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 3</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 4</div>
</div>
```

```css
.PseudoTable {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 18px 8px;
}

.Key {
  background: #FFE082;
}

.Value {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #90CAF9;
}
```

Most obvious solution (`flex-grow: 1` for `.Value`) does not work.

Current displaying is:

[image]

### Unacceptable solution

Please do not change the markup.
The wrapping of each `.Key` and `.Value` pairs in row wrapper is simple solution but if I accepted it, I did not ask this question. The multirow flex (and grid) layout conception is avoiding of row wrappers!

Comment: **I mean wrap this one row into div make this as flex.**
like HTML tag as,
<div class="PseudoTable" role="table">
  <div class="d-flex">
     <div class="Key" role="columnheader">A</div>
     <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 1</div>
  </div>
</div>
**In css**, 

.PseudoTable {display:block} .d-flex{display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;gap: 18px 8px;} 
I hope it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is, flexbox isn’t meant to do that. Its purpose is to align a bunch of boxes on a single axis (horizontally or vertically). There’s possibility to let objects wrap to next line, but that’s pretty much it.

What you’re trying to achieve DOES require a row element so that each pair can work on a full width basis.

**BUT**, what you wanna do is actually doable with… Good old float.

```css
.PseudoTable {
  width: 300px;
}

.Key {
  background: #FFE082;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.Value {
  background: #90CAF9;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="PseudoTable" role="table">
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">A</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 1</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 2</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 3</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value">Value 4</div>
</div>
```

But please note that this has major caveats and might behave badly if the content was to be changed. Check what happen if you put lipsum in Key or Value cell.

Comment: I would add `clear:left` to the keys and you won't have any issue even if the content change

Comment: Thank your for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The layout you want won't work with `flex-grow` alone because this property only consumes free space. This is the space remaining after all other lengths have been factored in.

So why would the other elements wrap when they don't have to? There's space on the row for them, as you showed in your example:

[image]

Grid layout isn't a simple solution either, because the first column will take the width of the longest item. You would need to created multiple columns and targeted spans. Gets complicated.

```css
.PseudoTable {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  gap: 18px 8px;
}

.Key {
  background: #FFE082;
}

.Value {
  background: #90CAF9;
}
```

```html
<div class="PseudoTable" role="table">
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">A</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 1</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 2</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 3</div>
  <div class="Key" role="columnheader">AAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="Value" role="cell">Value 4</div>
</div>
```

I think you'll need a (JavaScript) solution that calculates the width of the `.Key` element and the subtracts it from a full width `.Value` element and any margins you have.